# Completely hide the menu bar in 2.8

Tags: interface

Is it possible in 2.8 to completely collapse the menu bar as it was possible in 2.79?
[image]

left: 2.79, right: 2.8

I tried hiding the menu, deleting all workspace tabs individually, entering full screen mode,
but I still can't get rid of the top bar. Is there a reason it is handled this way in 2.8?

Comment: Hello :). I believe in 2.79 the 'menu' worked like any other editor, so it could be moved and closed. In 2.8, it is a separate UI element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible, unfortunately.You cannot hide the top bar completely in Blender versions starting from 2.8.

I know it's far from perfect solution, but if you create a new window, it will not have the top bar:

[image]

But you will still have to have the main window with the top bar somewhere.

Comment: Okay, 'new window' is an okay workaround when in a pinch (laptop). With the statusbar gone in 2.8 und moved to statistics for the active window it would be nice to have another option to save screen space.